# How do I dynamically change the text of a CMFCRibbonLabel

Tags: c++, label, ribbon, statusbar, mfc-feature-pack

My `CMDIFrameWndEx` derived main frame window uses a `CMFCRibbonStatusBar` to which I add a `CMFCRibbonLabel`.

I'd like to change the text of this label at runtime:

```
m_pLabel->SetText(description);
m_pLabel->Redraw();
```

It only updates the text but not the rectangle in which to draw it. So if the original text was too short, the new string won't be visible completely.

How do I get it to resize correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question again...

I worked around the issue by adding and removing the label instead of trying to change the text.

#### Code for adding the label:

```
CMFCRibbonLabel* pLabel = new CMFCRibbonLabel(description);
pLabel->SetID(ID_MYLABEL); // ID is 0 by default

m_wndStatusBar.AddDynamicElement(pLabel);
m_wndStatusBar.RecalcLayout();
m_wndStatusBar.RedrawWindow();
```

Note that I'm setting an ID so I can later call `CMFCRibbonStatusBar::RemoveElement()` with that ID.
The calls to `RecalcLayout()` and `RedrawWindow()` are needed to make the changes visible.

#### Code for removing the label:

```
if(m_wndStatusBar.RemoveElement(ID_MYLABEL))
{
    m_wndStatusBar.RecalcLayout();
    m_wndStatusBar.RedrawWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to remove and re-add. Just call this:

```
m_wndStatusBar.ForceRecalcLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

use the CMFCRibbonStatusBarPane::SetAlmostLargeText function